# JTextfield should trigger all keyboard inputs

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jtextfield, keylistener

I want to trigger all keyboard inputs (also strg, alt and tab) in a JTextField.

```
super.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }
});
```

KeyListener does not trigger keyboard inputs like strg, alt or / and tab.

Is there a solution for this case?

I need this for a settings screen, where the user can change the key, which must be pressed for a action like moving forward.

Comment: *"I want to trigger all keyboard inputs (also strg, alt or tab) in a JTextField."*  Why?  What feature does that provide to the end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, I had to disable traversal in order to catch the `Tab` key.
Also note that the `keyTyped()` event is never called for keys like `Alt`, `Shift` or `Control`.
But you can catch them when you use the `keyPressed()` or `keyReleased()` events:

```
public class Scribble extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    public Scribble(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.addKeyListener(this);
        /*
         * Disable tab, so we can catch it
         */
        field.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        this.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key typed: " + e.getKeyCode());
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key released: " + e.getKeyCode());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scribble();
    }
}
```